# Mysql Query for logarithmic aging

Tags: mysql

I want to implement a 'logarithmic' score-decay based on aging, and I'm trying to figure out the SUM/LOG combination. Here you have a simplified version of the current query:

```
SELECT SUM(1) as total_score FROM posts
JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.post_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

I'm currently doing SELECT 'SUM(1) as total_score' but I want to modify the query to take the date/age of the vote into consideration; where a vote from today weights 1, a vote from 15 days ago weights close to .8 and a vote from 30 days ago close to 0. I'm storing the date field on the votes table (vote_date) as a unix_timestamp.

[image]

I'm not really concerned about the WHERE clausule; that's pretty straightforward. What I'm trying to figure out is the logarithmic aging part.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two parts to your answer. First, the weighting function and then the SQL implementation.

Wegighting function:

According to your graph, you don't want a log weight buit rather parabolic.

From this you have to solve

Xc = y

where

```
X = [1 1 1 ;
    15^2 15 1;
    30^2 30 1];
```

and

```
y = [1;.8;0];
```

you get c = X^(-1)y or in matlab

```
c = X\y
```

Now you have the appropriate wieights of the quadratic function you depicted; namely y = ax^2+bx+c with (a,b,c) =(-.0013,.0073,.9941).

SQL part:

you select statement should look like (assuming the column of interest is named "age")

```
SELECT (-.0013*age*age + .0073*age + .9941) as age_weighted
```

Hope it helps

Cheers

---

Here 's the complete Matlab code (also to doublecheck solution)

```
X = [1 1 1 ;
    15^2 15 1;
    30^2 30 1];

y = [1;.8;0];

c = X\y;

x= (1:30)';
y = [x.^2 x ones(30,1)]*c;

figure(1)
clf;hold on
plot(x,y)
plot([1 15 30],[1 .8 0],'o')
```

[image: Matlab output]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function `WEIGHT(age)` that gives the weight of a vote that's `age` days old.

Then your query would be

```
    SELECT SUM(WEIGHT(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, votes.date_vote_cast))) as total_score,
           posts.post_id
      FROM posts
      JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.post_id
     WHERE votes.date_vote_cast <= CURRENT_DATE
       AND votes.date_vote_cast > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  GROUP BY post_id
  ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

I am afraid I don't know exactly what function you want for `WEIGHT(age)`. But you do, and you can work it out.

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out how to do a logarithmic weight on MYSQL; not worried about the WHERE clausule.

Comment: Well, the function for which you showed a graph is a circular function, not logarithmic. Many people, when using time-based weighting, use an exponential decay function. But those functions only asymptotically approach zero.

Answer (score 0):

I havent done the SQL part but I found a function that will provide the decay you are after, mathematically at least

```
y=(sqrt(900-(x^2)))/30
```

or in your case

```
score=(sqrt(900-(days^2)))/30
```

[image]

Hope it can help!